How do I await async Task{} with swift-snapshot-testing?
I'm introducing the framework swift-snapshot-testing into my SWIFTUI app.
https://swiftpackageindex.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing
https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing
How do I make sure that the snapshotting awaits async tasks in the view?
I have a SwiftUI view that loads data using it's .task{}. I have mocked out the observable ViewModel, but the snapshotting happens before the async .task{} finishes and the ViewModel triggers re-rendering of the view.
Here is the test:
func testPrintersListViewSnapShot() {
        
        let mockedPrinterResult: [PrinterModel] = [
            PrinterModel.moc(status: .maintenance, id: 1)
        ]
        
        Task {
            given(await printerControllerMock.fetchPrinters()).willReturn(.success(mockedPrinterResult))
        }
        
        let printersViewModel = PrintersViewModel(printerController: printerControllerMock, errorHandler: errorHandlerMock)
        
        let sut = PrintersListView(printersViewModel: printersViewModel)
        
        assertSnapshot(of: sut, as: .image)
    }

The thing here is:

I need to configure the printerControllerMock async, because it's an async call. (Is there any other way to do that?)
When the PrinterListView is instantiated, it uses .task{} to fetch the printers via the function mocked in the printersViewModel.

But it seems like the snapshotting is happening before the .task{} finishes.
Are there any way to delay that or ideally wait for that?

If this is SwiftUI you shouldn't have view model objects since that is what the View structs are. Just change that func to async, remove the Task and call it from .task and set the result on @State.

This package seems to erase the greatness of async/await. Floating tasks that you can’t track are a thing of the past.

@malhal We are using MVVM and it makes perfectly sense to have the view code separated from the view model code - especially in large applications like ours. I'm not sure what func you want me to make async. The view is already fetching async from the .task{}. The view model printers collection is already observable and a StateObject. The problem here is that the snapshot test assertion is not waiting for the .task{} in the view.

Yes the code should be separated but the async func should be in a controller struct that takes params and returns results, not in an object with its own properties. You should be avoiding MVVM type objects in SwiftUI because of the shared mutable state problem that its use of View struct is designed to avoid.

@loremipsum It's not the snapshot framework doing untrackable async here. It's instantiating a SwiftUI view (which in it self is not waitable). And the view has a .task{} closure. THAT is not trackable, so how should the snapshot framework be able to wait for the .task{} on the view, to finish?
If anything, SwiftUI's View instantiation is erasing the greatness of async/await. You can instantiate a View, that has a .task{} closure, but you can't await it.

@malhal I think you are reading more into my VM pattern that's relevant. Sounds like you are opinionated about VMs, maybe from your own experience. My Vms does not have a shared mutable state problem. Let's focus on the problem at hand here: The View struct has a .task{} closure - I don't know how you want that to be in a controller with params and results?
So the View instantiation (and the .task{} async closure) is not waitable, which doesn't allow the test framework to waith for the view invocation.

If you don’t use Task or hide async/await you can set a bool to true at the beginning of task  and false at the end. It is fantastic because you always know when something is in progress so you can update UI accordingly. This takes it all away, and you truly don’t know when something is done.

@loremipsum Thanks, that's an idea. I do have a loading spinner toggled by a boolean in the view, but speaking about a thing of the past, that solution really should a thing of the past. :-) But thanks for the idea, I will try it out.
